# Finding reference images

Tags: modeling

On Blender I like to model helicopters, guns, cars, tanks. The modelling isn't the problem. The problem is getting reference images of the small details, Most of the things I need I can just search on google and find a picture of it. The problem comes when for example I was modelling a AH-6 Little bird and finding what the avionics and general interior is a nightmare, any suggestions of efficient ways of getting reference images?

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: Any of these help? https://www.google.com/search?q=ah-6+interior&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1669&bih=866&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP0JfZqrPQAhVh6YMKHciXCNAQsAQIGg#tbm=isch&q=ah-6+helicopter+interior

Answer (score 0):

just registered to the site, and asked a question, and well, just probing around the site, maybe I can provide an answer too.  community contributor, first day.

so, the follow is opinion, yet, possibly a relevant one.  A suggestion as to the reason that it is difficult to find images of current military flight controls and weapons systems and those configurations is that they are classified as top secret.  I make no claims of being a modeler, and as that is the case, if I were modeling, I would make assumptions to the controls / weapon systems, and use a let your imagination run wild approach.